# Excel Macro not working after Updating System to Windows10 64-bit from Windows8 32-bit

Tags: excel, vba, msxml2

I have using below code in Windows8 32-bit System and it was working fine but same code is not working in Windows10 64-bit System.

```
URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=" & scripID & Chr(38) & "illiquid=0" & Chr(38) & "smeFlag=0" & Chr(38) & "itpFlag=0"
Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
xmlHttp.send    
sNo = InStr(1, xmlHttp.responseText, "id=" & Chr(34) & "responseDiv")
getNSEData = Trim(Mid(xmlHttp.responseText, sNo, InStr(sNo, xmlHttp.responseText, "/div>") - sNo))
```

I tried to install msxml2.dll in system by coping file in both "C:\Windows\System32\" & "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\". But still issue comes.

I want alternate of above code for Windows10 64-bit System.

Comment: "Not working" and "issue comes" do not sufficiently describe the problem.

Comment: After running macro it was taking long time to run the code and no data is fetching to excel from web.